# What is the difference between “dot” and “point” in decimals reading?

Tags: numbers

Can I use these words for decimals like 0.1 reading?

Comment: Your question is interesting, but doesn't provide reference to any research that you may have done yourself.

Comment: The only time I say "dot" is reading IP addresses or section numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For decimals, the only generally accepted way to read "." is "point"—it is the decimal **point**, after all, not the decimal dot.

That said, things aren't as clear cut for numbers that look like decimals, but use the period as a separator rather than a decimal point. For example, "Web 2.0" or "Section 3.2.1". In these cases, it seems both are acceptable. According to [ZDNet's article](http://www.zdnet.com/article/poll-2-0-do-you-say-2-dot-or-point-0/), both tend to be used.

Answer (score 0):

'Dot' is not used. 'Point' is the English word for the decimal point.

You could say that number as one of:

'Nought point one',
'Point one' or
'Zero point one'.

Comment: "Dot" *is* sometimes used, when speaking the term in the US.  It's up to the speaker to decide which to use in informal settings.